# How to find all the quadrangles of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, networkx

Is there a method in `[networkx][1]` that list all the quadrangles of a graph? If there isn't, can you please point me to the algorithm that does this so I can possibly write it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.triangles.html?

Comment: Should I post as an answer?

Comment: @EdChum no because i said it's similar to what I need but it's not this. I want the quadrangles and that counts the triangles

Comment: Ah ok, will deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the networkx but if you want to develop your own algorithm you may use graph spanning and then apply the quadrangles algorithm.
The algorithm is explained on the wiki in a good manner 
`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_quadrangle`